# Instantiating Qt application and widget within Googletest results in __acrt_first_block == header assertion fail

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, googletest

I am creating a simple Qt window application with CMake and decided I to use googletest for unit testing. Unfortunately, when creating my main window widget within a single test, I sometimes receive an assertion fail message: `__acrt_first_block == header`. I have already set all CMakeLists to use /MTd runtime mode (as google test library does, `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "/MTd"`).

Assertion failed message window leads me to the comment in gtest source stating: `// We create the exception message on the heap because VC++ prohibits creation of objects with destructors on stack in functions using __try (see error C2712).`

Obviously, every Qt object defines a custom destructor so the problem lies here. But what's the way around to make those tests work? Can I somehow instantiate my mainwindow globally once in tests.cpp file rather than individually in every test?

```
class CalcTests : public testing::Test
{
protected:
    Calc* calc = nullptr;
    
    void SetUp() override
    {
        calc = new Calc{};
    }

    void TearDown() override
    {
        delete calc;
    }
};

// A sample test...
TEST_F(CalcTests, sin_pi_6)
{
    //auto calc = std::make_unique<Calc>(nullptr);
    calc->menuViewScientificTriggered(); // just in case

    const double pi_rounded = disp_rounding(std::numbers::pi).toDouble();
    calc->getCurrDisplay()->setText(disp_rounding(pi_rounded / 6));

    calc->sinClicked();
    const QString actual{ calc->getCurrDisplay()->text() };
    const QString expected{ "0.5" };

    ASSERT_EQ(actual, expected) << "\n\n\n"
                    << "Expected: " << expected.toStdString() << "\nActual: " << actual.toStdString();
}
```

I've also read that templates may cause this assertion fail. But in my case they are only two of them and there are fairly simple. They are not explicitly allocating memory on heap, but I attach sample source for reference:

```
template<typename Float>
bool nearly_equal(const Float a, const Float b, const Float eps_factor)
    requires std::is_floating_point_v<Float>
{
    const auto abs_a = std::abs(a);
    const auto abs_b = std::abs(b);
    
    return std::abs(abs_a - abs_b)
        <= std::numeric_limits<Float>::epsilon() * eps_factor;
}
```

Comment: I've separated GUI from core and now I am creating only data struct inside every test (and it does not define custom destructor). However, the problem with assertion failure still occurs...